# ¿Por qué este bucle no actualiza correctamente este array?

Tags: javascript

Intento hacer un bucle que añada al array `fibSeq = [0,1]`  la suma de los dos numeros anteriores .

Es decir el resultado con 6 iteraciones debería ser este: `fibSeq = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]`

Sin embargo el mio no actualiza:

```js
function fib(num){
 var fibSeq = [0,1];
 var elultimo = fibSeq.length -1
 var elanterior = elultimo - 1
 var suma = elultimo + elanterior
 
 for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
  fibSeq.push(suma)
   }
 return fibSeq
}

fib(6)
```

Y da como resultado `fibSeq = [0,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

He probado a incluir las declaraciones dentro del bucle

```js
function fib(num){
 var fibSeq = [0,1];
 var elultimo = fibSeq.length -1
 var elanterior = elultimo - 1
 var suma = elultimo + elanterior
 
 for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
  elultimo = fibSeq.length -1
  elanterior = elultimo - 1
  suma = elultimo + elanterior
  fibSeq.push(suma)
   }
 return fibSeq
}

fib(6)
```

Pero entonces me da unos numeros raros, no los que quiero (los que quiero son los fibonacci) : `[0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]`

Agradecería una explicación de porqué el bucle no se actualiza en vez de una solución de como obtener los numeros fibonacci ya que ando haciendo esto para aprender JS e intento evitar soluciones completas porque si no no aprendo. Gracias.

Comment: Creía que sabía JS hasta que me encontré con este problema. Ahora me doy cuenta que no se hacer ni bucles bien todavía xD

Comment: Es que estas haciendo "de 0 a n sumame los valores de la posición 0 y la posicion 1". Tendras que sumar los anteriores no siempre el primero con el segundo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema está en las primeras líneas:

```
var elultimo = fibSeq.length -1
var elanterior = elultimo - 1
```

Porque se coge el valor `0` y el valor `1` y se "pushean" tantas veces como `num`, ya que se hace fuera del bucle, además de que tienes el valor del `length` no del valor que ocupa esa posición del bucle.

La solución más directa y sin modificar mucho el código original es, precisamente, acceder a los valores del array y sumarlos:

```js
function fib(num){
 var fibSeq = [0,1];
 for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    var length = fibSeq.length;
    var last = fibSeq[length-1];
    var prevLast = fibSeq[length-2];
    var suma = last + prevLast;
  fibSeq.push(suma)
 }
 return fibSeq
}

console.log(fib(6));
```

Cierta mejora que propongo yo es usar sintaxis de la última versión de Javascript, la ES6:

```js
function fib(num){
 let fibSeq = [0,1];
 for (let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    const length = fibSeq.length,
          last = fibSeq[length-1],
          prevLast = fibSeq[length-2],
          suma = last + prevLast;
  fibSeq.push(suma)
 }
 return fibSeq
}

console.log(fib(6));
```

Answer (score 5):

Una propuesta alternativa, usando menos variables:

```js
function fibonacci( lim ) {
  var ret = [ 0, 1 ],
      curr = 1,
      temp;

  while( true ) {
    temp = ret[curr] + ret[curr - 1];

    if( temp > lim ) break;

    ret.push( temp );
    ++curr;
  }

  return ret;
}

console.log( fibonacci( 50 ) );
```

Comment: @JavierCake Es el código que usé en tu pregunta del otro día. Eliminé la respuesta, pero esto aun puede servir :-)

Answer (score 3):

Y otra posible respuesta:

```js
let fibSeq = [0, 1];
let num = 10;//numero de iteraciones

for (let I = 1; I < num; I++) {
  let F = [];// un array trmporal, una copia del fibSeq
  fibSeq.map((f, j) => {
    F[j] = f;
  });
  //suma los dos últimos números y agregalos al array
  for (let i = I; i < F.length; i++) {
    fibSeq.push(F[i] + F[i - 1]);
  }
}

console.log(fibSeq);
```